# Shopping cart saved in firebase - order processing

Tags: xcode, firebase, shopping-cart

my next question is about Firebase.
I have an application with spare parts for a car. In the application, a user authorized by email and password adds spare parts to his cart, which is stored in Firebase.

Question: how, by clicking the "submit order" button, send the contents of the cart to the seller (me) by mail?

Perhaps Firebase already has a ready-made solution / service for a similar task?

Does Apple's policy allow you to send the user's email address that was provided during registration for order feedback along with the request?

Here i trying to send order by MFMailComposeViewController

```
@IBAction func sendRequestButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

// Modify following variables with your text / recipient
let recipientEmail = "MyMail@gmail.com"
let subject = "description"
var body = "some array with ordered spare parts"
for i in objectsList {
    body.append(i.objectFromPartsCatalogueListCode! + " " +  i.objectFromPartsCatalogueListName!+"\n")
}
// Show default mail composer
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self //!!!
    mail.delegate = self //!!!
    mail.setToRecipients([recipientEmail])
    mail.setSubject(subject)
    mail.setMessageBody(body, isHTML: false)
    mail.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(mail, animated: true)
    
    // Show third party email composer if default Mail app is not present
} else if let emailUrl = SendEmailManager.createEmailUrl(to: recipientEmail, subject: subject, body: body) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(emailUrl)
}
```

It is difficult and opens an additional menu for choosing the method of sending. I want to receive an order with content from the application on my mail, one click by the user of the "sendRequest" button.

Comment: If you're asking how to programmatically generate or send an email, there are a lot of solutions. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include the code you've attempted and we'll take a look

Comment: Thank for your attention, i clarified my question.

Comment: Why send an email at all? Emails can fail to send or be routed to junk or blocked entirely. Why not respond within the app itself? The seller could easily be notified of the transaction with a listing of the items - all within the app.

Comment: I agree, you are right, but how to implement it?

Comment: I think the answer provided by @Hydra touches on the solution: The user selects the parts he wants and adds them to his cart, which is stored in Firebase. When they complete the transaction that data is copied into a document within a collection the seller has access to and has an observer on. When the data is written to that collection, the seller will receive a Firebase event (because he has an observer on that collection) and can process the order from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily send emails from your app via a secure backend environment (eg. cloud functions).

There are many possible solutions, but here is one of them:

When a user hits submit, you can create a new document in a special Firestore collection (eg. emails) and have a cloud function listening to changes in that collection using a background trigger [Firestore event triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). This function will get the document changes, retrieve its data (email information, and any other metadata you've specified), and send an email using whichever email API you decide to use (eg SendGrid).

Alternatively, you can use the Firebase email extension [Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email), but writing your own function isn't difficult.

An added benefit is you can store your personal email in your secure backend environment so your users won't be able to access it on their devices.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me.